# Why do I get an 'Access Denied' error when trying to connect to 'localhost'?

Tags: c#, server

I am making an app that writes a some file content to a server as html in c#. The thing is that it should work, but it somehow doesn't.

I've checked the code multiple times, copied the exact code from a tutorial and modified it to fit my needs; but somehow it still doesn't work (even though it has worked before).

```
public Server(string filename) 
        {
            chatNames = filename;
            try
            {
                string content;
                HttpListener server = new HttpListener();// this is the http server
                server.IgnoreWriteExceptions = true;
                server.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1/");
                server.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost/");

                server.Start();

                while (true)
                {
                    content = FileR(filename);
                    HttpListenerContext context = server.GetContext();
                    //context: provides access to httplistener's response

                    HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;
                    //the response tells the server where to send the datas

                    string page = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/" + filename + ".txt";
                    //this will get the page requested by the browser

                    if (page == string.Empty)  //if there's no page, we'll say it's index.html
                        page = "index.html";

                    TextReader tr = new StreamReader(page);
                    string msg = tr.ReadToEnd();  //getting the page's content

                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
                    //then we transform it into a byte array

                    response.ContentLength64 = buffer.Length;  // set up the messasge's length
                    Stream st = response.OutputStream;  // here we create a stream to send the message
                    st.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); // and this will send all the content to the browser

                    context.Response.Close();  // here we close the connection
                    hasRan = true;
                }
            } catch (Exception e)
            {
                hasRan = false;
                error = e.Message;
            }
        }

        private string FileR(string name)
        {
            string content = string.Empty;
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(chatNames);

            if (IsFileLocked(fi))
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(chatNames))
                {

                    //viewMessage.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Left;
                    content = sr.ReadToEnd();

                }
            }
            else
            {
                content = "Please try again later";
                Thread.Sleep(350);
            }
            return content;
        }
```

I've looked everywhere online and I still couldn't find something that answers my question. If I missed something online, please notify.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1. run the app in admin mode.

Option 2. Run HttpListener in non-admin mode. All you need to do is grant permissions to the particular URL. e.g.

```
`netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:80/MyUri user=DOMAIN\user`
```

Comment: Yes. I do. Any ideas?

Comment: The exact error is 
```
  System.Net.HttpListenerException
  HResult=0x80004005
  Message=Access is denied
  Source=System
```